# AJAX call leak memory

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory

I have this simple code retrieving data via Ajax.

But there seems to be a memory leak, couse for every request (for the same) the memory usage going 2-3mb up with no ending, until IE locksup.

What have i missing, how to release the memory. There is no leak if data is not outputted to
$('#divTimeEdit').html();

```
function EditTime(timeid) {
  if ($('#divTimeEdit').length) {

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async: false,
        url : 'index.php?func=timeeditdesktop',
        data : {
            times : timeid
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#divTimeEdit').html(data);
        }
    })
  };
}
```

Comment: what's the idea behind the `$('#divTimeEdit').length` check?

Comment: I would like to show your timeeditdesktop function in PHP

Comment: If you're appending a lot of data to the DOM, memory use *will* go up.
This is not a leak, this is simply the browser allocating more space to put all that data from your request in.
If it is a ridiculously large set of data, your browser might freeze or even crash in very bad cases.

Comment: @TimothyGroote is right. You might want to consider breaking up your requests into smaller "packets" so you will give the browser runtime some time for rendering and none of these freezes will accure.

Comment: Timothy > Correct, the $('#divTimeEdit').length, does not do anything to the code after its moved to a function. Its removed now.

Comment: The problem is indeed coming from the php function. when there is no die(); at the end and it just builds up data. Thanks.